# Complex typedef in UML

Tags: c++, uml, typedef

I would like to know how I can represent complex typedef like the following in UML:

```cpp
class Foo {
protected:
   typedef std::pair<uint64_t, Bar> BarPair;
   typedef std::set<BarPair> BarPairSet;

   std::map<uint32_t, BarPairSet> m_indexedBarPairSet
};
```

`Bar` is not part of `Foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to represent your *typedefs*, of course it is possible to have for instance the class *BarPair* with a dependency to the template class *pair* but there is no standard way to support the binding.

In case it is not for instance *typedef std::pair BarPair* but *BarPair : public std::pair {}* we have

[image]

So what about to extend UML with the stereotype *typedef* to have something like that :

[image]

or to stereotype the realization with *typedef-bind* and to use the stereotype *typedef* for *BarPair* and *BarPairSet*

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What is a software that your using to represent blocks (BarPair and BarPairSet) inside a class?

Comment: I use the modeler I developed, BoUML ( https://www.bouml.fr/ ). The pictures are class diagrams, in them for some classes I asked to hide separators through the *drawing settings* asking to hide attributes/operations

Answer (score 1):

For structures you can use a `<<dataType>>` (see pp. 165 of UML 2.5). (Part of) your code would look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it is clear, but it does not represent the binding between the uint64_t and the Bar object.
In your situation, the class Foo is represented as a package?

Comment: No. It's just an enlarged presentation of the class so the datarType optically fits.